# Can I start windows explorer with focus in the address bar?

Tags: windows-explorer

I like to launch explorer via the win+e shortcut.  However I'd like to start with focus in the address bar so I can quickly go to some directory.  Can I do this?  Is there some autohotkey script for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer as the original script did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following [Edit]AutoHotKey[/Edit] script simulates pressing F4 which can be used to go to the address bar:

```
#e::
Run explorer.exe
WinWait ahk_class ExploreWClass,,1000
Send {F4}
```

Seems to work OK for me on Windows XP.

Comment: ?????? What language had you use? It's not .BAT, .VBS ou .JS!

Comment: The original post asked for an AutoHotKey script. Therefore I don't think the downvote was deserved.

Comment: thanks.  I added a Send {Esc} so that the drop down that pops up when you hit F4 is closed and it just leaves the current folder selected in the address bar